# Combine two dataframes by two same variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes (df1 and df2 ) and want to merge them into one df with the columns "GEO", "POP","Value","Mean"
not matching rows should be assigned with "NA"

```
> df1
        GEO    Value            POP
1         Belgium   986494    Adolescents
2         Denmark   542496    Adolescents
3         Finland   472801    Adolescents
4          France  6568728    Adolescents
5        Germany   6177477    Adolescents
6           Italy  4564035    Adolescents
7     Netherlands  1608971    Adolescents
8           Spain  3550102    Adolescents
9  United Kingdom  5815087    Adolescents
10        Belgium  6910856         Adults
11        Denmark  3423077         Adults
12        Finland  3318043         Adults
13         France 39536853         Adults
14       Germany  50839124         Adults
15          Italy 37609721         Adults
16    Netherlands 10467463         Adults
17          Spain 29722963         Adults
18 United Kingdom 39436511         Adults

> df2
              GEO            POP    Mean
1         Belgium    Adolescents 1221.75
2         Denmark    Adolescents 2669.66
3         Finland    Adolescents 1378.44
4          France    Adolescents 2293.82
5         Germany    Adolescents 2412.83
6           Italy    Adolescents 1282.08
7     Netherlands    Adolescents 1431.87
8           Spain    Adolescents 5410.47
9  United Kingdom    Adolescents 1026.75
10        Belgium         Adults 1567.43
11        Denmark         Adults 4241.10
12        Finland         Adults 3938.95
13         France         Adults 3231.94
14        Germany         Adults 1840.54
15          Italy         Adults 1337.15
16    Netherlands         Adults 4157.15
17          Spain         Adults 3897.04
```

I need to combine them into one df!
I tried some function with dplyr:

```
bind_rows(df1,df2)
```

- Problems: they  have different lenghts! So I tried INTERSECT

```
intersect(df1, df2)

Error: not compatible: 
- Cols in y but not x: `Value`. 
- Cols in x but not y: `Mean`.
```

I also tried to join

```
left_join(df1,df2, by "GEO", "POP")
```

but this is only possible by one one common column, and I would have two columns /GEO and POP) that have to be considered in the join process.
Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 %>%
    left_join(df2, by = c("GEO", "POP"))
```

Comment: Sorry I discovered a mistake in the database. Every 8th position NA appears in the last colmn. I checked both datasets and the result does not make any sense

Comment: I found the mistake. In the original df2 there was one spacecharacter behind the Country "Germany " df1 had no spacecharacter behind "Germany". That is why after a leftjoin both attributes did not appear to be the same. Is there an additional line, where I can prevent those silly issues?

Comment: No. In that case you need to edit the column, e.g. with `gsub(" ", "", [your column])` to remove whitespaces.